# How to copy a flattened 2D array from Global Memory to Shared Memory in CUDA

Tags: c, cuda, parallel-processing, nvidia

I have a kernel receiving a flattened 2D array, and I would like to copy one Line of the array each time the shared memory, my kernel looks like the following :

```
__global__ void searchKMP(char *test,size_t pitch_test,int ittNbr){
    int  tid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int strideId = tid * 50;

    int m = 50;

    __shared__ char s_test[m];

    int j;
               //this loops over the number of lines in my 2D array           
                   for(int k=0; k<ittNbr; k++){

                   //this loops to store my flattened (basically threats 1 line at a time) array into shared memory     
                   if(threadIdx.x==0){
                     for(int n =0; n<50; ++n){
                    s_test[n] = *(((char*)test + k * pitch_test) + n);

                }
             }
            __syncthreads();


             j=0;

            //this is loop to process my shared memory array against another 1D array
             for(int i=strideID; i<(strideID+50); i++{
             ...dosomething...
             (increment x if a condition is met) 
             ...dosomething...
             }
             __syncthreads();
             if(x!=0)
                cache[0]+=x;

            ...dosomething...

}
```

although when I verify the values of x, the value of x varies, all the times, or varies with the number of threads. Example, 10 blocks of 500 threads returns 9 when 20 blocks of 250 threads is returning the value 7 or 6 depending of the executions. I wonder if the problem is coming from the 2D flattened array copied in shared memory or if something is done wrong in this bit of code.

Comment: How many threads per block are you running with this kernel?

Comment: 20 blocks of 500 threads or 10 blocks of a thousand

Comment: OK, so why is every thread in the block trying to load data into your shared memory array for? As written, that very sketchy kernel code you have shown makes little sense, I am afraid....

Comment: that's true I actually changed that to be sure that every data I try to load is only loaded once and then shared amongst the threads

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your array in shared memory has 20 elements:

```
   int m = 20;
   __shared__ char s_test[m];
```

But in your inner loop you are trying to write 50 elements:

```
   for(int n =0; n<50; ++n){
      s_test[n] = *(((char*)test + k * pitch_test) + n);
```

I don't know if this is specifically the problem you were looking for, but that looks like it won't work.

Comment: That's right, I actually made a mistake, because I've been changing the code so much to try to find what makes the code wrong :/  but thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

shared memory is shared across all threads in the same block

it is not very clear, why you need shared memory and what you are doing:

in your code all threads in the block write the same values to your shared memory many times, but it is redundantly

common way to work with shared memeory is something like this:

```
if(threadIdx.x < m)
  s_test[threadIdx.x] = *(global_mem_pointer + threadIdx.x);

__syncthreads();
```

all threads in the block write their own value "at the same moment" and after `__syncthreads();` your memory is filled with what you need and visible for all threads in the block